# entity framework как настроить cultureInfo?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, валидация, .net

При загрузке из бд данные типа double отображаются с разделителем "," При попытке ввести или сохранить дробное с таким разделителем - валидация на странице пишет "значение должно быть числом". Т.е. пропускает ввод только с разделителем "."
При вводе чисел с разделителем "." - в контроллере ModelStat.IsValid - false и список ошибок - введенные значения недопустимы, т.е. требует разделитель ","
В Web.config `<globalization culture="ru-RU" uiCulture="ru"/>` - как настроить валидацию, чтобы разделитель был ","?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно переопределять скрипты валидации на клиенте.

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
    $.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
        var globalizedValue = value.replace(",", ".");
        return this.optional(element) || (globalizedValue >= param[0] && globalizedValue <= param[1]);
    }

    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/.test(value);
    }
    </script>
}
```